# FreeHGlobal Corrupt Heap

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, user32

So I'm working on adding a feature to out software, and I need to travel from C# to C++ with some data, then return back t C# with return data. We have a system in place to make this possible, but it appears only my machine is having issues! We use...

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);
```

In our method to send the message, there is the following...

```
        hWndRecipient = (hWndRecipient == IntPtr.Zero) ? new IntPtr(AbstractLegacyABELApplication.MainWindowHandle) : hWndRecipient;
        COPYDATASTRUCT dataToSend = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
        dataToSend.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(message);
        dataToSend.dwData = (int)messageType;
        dataToSend.cbData = GlobalSize(dataToSend.lpData);
        SendMessage(hWndRecipient, WM_COPYDATA, hWndSender.ToInt32(), ref dataToSend);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataToSend.lpData);
```

This gets the data to the c++ layer without an issue, I can parse the message in xml, so it is easy to pull apart on the other side. Now when trying to send it back, I am doing the following (C++)...

```
        System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pCopyDataStruct->lpData);                     
        CString csOutgoing("SOME SORT OF MESSAGE TO SEND BACK HERE");
        pCopyDataStruct->lpData = (PVOID)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(csOutgoing);
        pCopyDataStruct->cbData = csOutgoing.GetLength();
```

For some reason, just on my machine, the first line crashes out, and visual studio gives me a corrupt heap error. If I comment out this line of code, and I ignore the risk of a memory leak for now just to try it out, the new message does not come back when I get back to C#, it is still the old message.

I have shelved these changes and given them to two other developers, and they were both able to build and run them without an issue.

I have tried getting our latest from source control, deleting the debug folder, re-copying the DLLs into there, clean, build, nothing seems to change anything for me, I still run into the same issues.

Anyone have some insight for me, getting really frustrated, and searches are coming up empty!

**EDIT**: It appears to be something wrong with my machine. If I build the projects in question and attempt to run the code outside of visual studio, it will crash, but if my co-worker builds the same shelf set, he can run it in and out of visual studio. I had him send me his builds of the files that have changes, and mine still crashes with his files...

**EDIT2**: So After endless trying, trouble shooting, we were unable to find a resolution. Building the same shelf set on co-workers machine, he could run it without an issue, both in debug, and just running the EXE. If he sent me his build, running on my system, it would crash. Had to find another work around, as we cannot give this to customers and risk this issue with one of them.

Comment: I suggest you only allocate memory once in c#, and free it once in c#. Use predefined buffer lengths.

Comment: I've tried to not release it in c++, but even after changing the value in c++, the old value is still seen in c# when it comes back... it is not making much sense

Comment: 0 down vote
 

You are not supposed to release the memory in the receiver, Windows already takes care of it. Do not re-use the COPYDATASTRUCT you get in your message handler, create a new one.